# Linker error from Boost: cannot find the libraries to link with

Tags: c++, qt, boost, linker, mingw

I have this linker error related to Boost:

```
error: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mgw44-mt-1_54
error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the part of the Qt pro file related to Boost:

```
BOOST_VERS = 1_54
COMPILER = mgw44

INCLUDEPATH += $$BOOST_ROOT/boost
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib

LIBS += -lboost_program_options-$$COMPILER-mt-$$BOOST_VERS
LIBS += -lboost_thread-$$COMPILER-mt-$$BOOST_VERS
LIBS += -lboost_system-$$COMPILER-mt-$$BOOST_VERS
```

BOOST_ROOT is an environment variable set to C:\Boost_1_54_0.

Since Boost seems to be installed correctly (the libraries are there), what am I doing wrong?

System:
- Windows 7
- MinGW 4.4
- Boost 1.54.0
- qmake / Qt Creator

Comment: Does the library file it's looking for actually exist?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Specifically does C:\Boost_1_54_0\stage\lib have a boost_program_options-mgw44-mt-1_54(.dll, or .lib or... no extension?) file?

Comment: try doing `LIBS += -L$$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib` in case the file actually exists

Comment: @benjymous - Yes, it exists.

Comment: @doctorlove - There *.a files, i.e. static libraries.

Comment: @TimMeyer - I added it, but I still get the same linker error.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't expand the lib name, so try passing the full name (instead of linker flag `-l...`): `libboost_program_options-mgw44-mt-1_54.a`

Comment: @IgorR. - Same result, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> `QMAKE_LIBDIR`
>
> This variable contains the location of all known library directories.
>   The value of this variable is typically handled by qmake or qmake.conf
>   and rarely needs to be modified.

Please, try to do it like this:

```
win32-g++* {
  LIBS           += $${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${BOOST_VERS}.a
  PRE_TARGETDEPS += $${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${BOOST_VERS}.a
}

linux-g++* {
  LIBS           += -L$${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib  -lboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${BOOST_VERS}
  PRE_TARGETDEPS +=   $${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib/libboost_system-$${COMPILER}-mt-$${BOOST_VERS}.a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Being BOOST_ROOT an environment variable, it must be used like this:

```
$$(BOOST_ROOT)
```

And BOOST_VERS must be used as:

```
$${BOOST_VERS}
```